# ionic/angular is not compatible with Angular 9

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

While updating to Angular 9 I am getting below errors.

```
Package "@ionic/angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular-devkit/core" (requires "7.2.1 - 8", would install "9.0.1").                                   
Package "@ionic/angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular-devkit/schematics" (requires "7.2.1 - 8", would install "9.0.1").           

Incompatible peer dependencies found.                                                                                                                                   
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.                                                  
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
```

Updating with force is proper way or should I wait for it. My ionic/angular version is as below.

```
"@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
```

Comment: ionic 5 has been released. You could try that

Comment: Yes I know, I thought I am using ionic 5 only. While checking npm outdated I come to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although running the following commands will upgrade you to Ionic 5 + Angular 9 (without the npm warning that you are getting):

```sh
npm install @ionic/angular@latest @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest
```

Next, run the following command. Like **@Tinaira** mentioned (in the comment), commit/stash any changes before running this command.

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
```

(Or pass --allow-dirty to the end of the command if you don't want to commit/stash your changes - NOT RECOMMENDED).

But later on, you might also face another issue of JIT compilation. Check this out [Ionic 5 with Angular 9 - Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60183056/ionic-5-with-angular-9-angular-jit-compilation-failed-angular-compiler-not)

Comment: about the second command. I have to add that if there comes an error "Repository is not clean. Please commit or stash any changes before updating." to just add --allow-dirty at the end of the command: ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty