# Ionic 5 with Angular 9 - Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

Ionic 5 was [announced](https://ionicframework.com/blog/announcing-ionic-5/) a few hours ago (12th Feb 2020) and I upgraded my one of the small production app to Ionic 5 along with Angular 9:

```sh
# To update to Ionic 5
npm install @ionic/angular@latest @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest --save-exact --save

# To update to Angular 9
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
```

But when I did `ionic serve`, I started getting the bellow error:

```
Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!
  - JIT compilation is discouraged for production use-cases! Consider AOT mode instead.
  - Did you bootstrap using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server'?
  - Alternatively provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.
    at getCompilerFacade (core.js:610)
    at Function.get (core.js:16065)
    at getInjectableDef (core.js:362)
    at injectableDefOrInjectorDefFactory (core.js:16816)
```

I came across a few Angular GitHub issues:

1. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16873
2. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32466

They are saying to include `import '@angular/compiler';` in `main.ts` file but when I matched one of my other Angular 9 application (which I updated recently), I don't see such configurations there.

Is Angular 9 not compatible with Ionic 5?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

## Updated & correct solution to fix this

Based on the answer from [Tran Quang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5992468/tr%e1%ba%a7n-quang-hi%e1%bb%87p), I went to see the [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) of `ionic-native` and came to know that they recently updated their package to compile with Angular 9.

Hence you need to update any/all dependencies of `@ionic-native`. For this, look at all the dependencies in your `package.gson` file which start with `@ionic-native/` and update them one by one.

For example, this is my `package.gson`:

[image]

So I had to run the following commands to update all my `@ionic-native` dependencies:

```sh
npm i @ionic-native/core@latest
npm i @ionic-native/camera@latest
npm i @ionic-native/firebase-x@latest
npm i @ionic-native/splash-screen@latest
npm i @ionic-native/status-bar@latest
```

Same you have to do for your `@ionic-native` dependencies. Just make sure, those are updated minimum to [`v5.21.5`](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#5215-2020-02-12) (because a few old releases were not working).

Cheers

If for some reason, you can't update your `@ionic-native` dependencies, look at my original answer for different workarounds/solutions ⬇️

---

## Original Answer

For me, the following solutions worked. Not sure if they are perfect to add but hoping the Ionic team will fix this as these solutions were not needed when I upgraded my plain Angular app to Angular 9.

### Solution 1

Turn off the AOT by changing `"aot": true` to `"aot: false` in `angular.json` file. I would not recommend this as this improves the performance of the Angular app and improves the catching of error codes in development mode.

### Solution 2

If you don't want to change in `angular.json` and wants to fix this issue for `ionic serve` only, pass the `--aot=false` flag to `ng` command by using `--`:

```sh
ionic serve -- --aot=false
```

### Solution 3 (blind option)

If none the solutions above are working for you, you can run a command `npm update` which will update literally all the dependencies from your `package.json` (that means, Ionic dependencies will also be updated).

This is a blind option because you won't have an idea that which dependencies are updated and what are the breaking changes in those updated dependencies. So you might end up fixing other issues because of this.

So it's up to you to take this risk :) Well, this is worth doing if your app is not that big or not using any codes which are removed in the newer dependencies.

### Solution 4 (the last & worst option)

Add `import '@angular/compiler';` in `main.ts` file. But this **might** increase the bundle size.

## Extra

While upgrading Ionic, you might face another issue because of wrong `import` in `polyfills.ts`. If yes, check out [src/zone-flags.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation after upgrading to Ionic 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60182031/2405040)

Comment: This works brilliantly up until I build for production:

`ionic cordova build android --prod --release --source-map`

Then we're back at the same error `Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!`

Comment: Have you tried remove `--source-map` from the production build?

Comment: Not one of these solutions on this entire page has worked for me, when I do a non-prod build for a test environment configuration: "ionic cordova build android --configuration uat". I always get the error "Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!"

Comment: Your some dependency must be outdated. Can you share your dependencies in a **text file** and share the link with me

Comment: Upgrading @ionic/native worked for me. Best to try and not include the compiler if possible as it's going to increase your output file size.

Comment: Yes @LeeGunn, I updated my answer. I added it in the very first post.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal - ah sorry, the comment wasn't aimed at you - I'm just adding weight to the "correct solution" and not the easy "include the compiler" which people might still be tempted to use.

Comment: I got your point @LeeGunn and that's okay if you were not aiming at the answer :) Because your comment made me rethink and I improved the answer by moving that option as last resort.

Comment: Updating `@ionic-native/` dependencies solved my issue when I built for production with: `ionic cordova build android --prod`. Thanks!

Comment: I am on angular 11. Updating ionic to latest didnt resolve the issue for me. I had to set aot:false

Answer (score 29):

For Angular:
Stopping the terminal and re-serve it `ng serve` solved the problem for me.

Comment: You sir, are a legend, you have no idea how much time I've lost and I could've just done this. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, it's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 6):

Try `ng serve --aot`, it helped me fix the problem, that's if you want to run with aot which is recommended since it will be similar to the production build and it will help you catch errors sooner.

Hope this helps.

Angular Link: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

Comment: Yes, that I'm aware of @Tony but my concern is that why this error didn't show up in the normal Angular application when upgraded to 9. It only occurred in the Ionic app. May be some configuration issue.

Answer (score 5):

Running `npm update` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Yes, that will also work of course, because `npm update` will literally update each & every dependency and you won't have an idea that what's updated & whatnot. That could also lead to other errors.

Answer (score 3):

Because of ionic update not fast enough, you can try:
`npm i @ionic-native/status-bar@beta @ionic-native/splash-screen@beta @ionic-native/core@beta -S` work for me.

update 2020/02/18 => we can run `npm i @ionic-native/status-bar @ionic-native/splash-screen @ionic-native/core -S` now to get latest stable version

Comment: Is this a question or you are trying to answer something?

Comment: Oh well, updating my @ionic-native dependencies to the latest stable versions actually worked for me.
None of the other workarounds mentioned here are needed then.

Answer (score 2):

Tried several ways, including `npm update`, with no success. The only way I could get Ionic 5 with Angular 9 to work in production mode, was setting `"aot": false` and `"buildOptimizer": false` in angular.json.

Comment: Same in my case. I am not sure, though, if it is a good practice to turn off "buildOptimizer" for production. My 'gut feeling' is telling me that's an absolute NO.

Comment: totally agree @ServerKhalilov, I am still investigating and "struggling" to make it work and publish a production build, instead of a dev build

Comment: Please, update your comment in case you figure out the solution.

Comment: I have been able to "pin it down" to the MSAL related components in package.json (@azure/msal-angular, cordova-plugin-msal, msal). One of those 3 npm packges has an incompatibility issue with IVY.

Comment: same for Me. Did any one solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

need to update ionic as well, it will work.
For angular when update version it updates all dependent itself. But in ionic need to update manually.

```
"@angular/common": "9.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "9.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "9.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "9.0.5",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "1.2.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "17.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/crop": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/document-viewer": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/image-picker": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/toast": "5.22.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually theres was no @ionic in my .json file.
But after lots of inspect, i found that i wrote some modules of angular forms(Validator, FormGroup, FromControl) within the import of ngModule.

And also used module in a wrong way,
Example: instead of importing MatSnackBarModule, import MatSnackBar in .ts file of that specific component where you want to import and similarly for other remaining modules also, dont write them with Module as suffix.

but import MatSnackBarModule entirely in app.module.ts file.

Note: I explained above taking MatSnackBar as example , it implies for anyother module as well.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Are you really answering the question? If you want, you can ask a separate question.