# Upgrade to Ionic 5 with Angular 9 from Ionic 4 / Angular 7

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

There is a [great tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=851HkqX3YQ4) on the official Ionic YouTube channel which will show you a best-case scenario for upgrading to Ionic 5 and Angular 9.

However for my simple prototype app that I had made last year (just a demo that let me reorder a list) I tried to update but almost immediately came off the rails.

It turned out to be using `"@angular/core": "^7.2.2"` which broke the app from `ionic serve` because it was expecting Angular 8.

Then I tried to run the `ng upgrade` but got hit with incompatible peer dependencies for `codelyzer`, `@ionic/angular-toolkit`, and `@angular/http`.

So I tried to upgrade to Angular 8 first with `npm i @angular/core@"~8.x.x"` but that failed as it needed `npm i zone.js@~0.9.1`.

How can I update successfully to the latest and greatest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for people coming from angular 7 it seems for this project the correct upgrade commands are:

```sh
npm i @ionic/angular@latest
npm i zone.js@~0.9.1
npm i @angular/core@"~8.x.x"
npm i @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest
npm i codelyzer@latest
npm remove @angular/http
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli --allow-dirty
```

and it finally updated everything. However I did see a warning saying `Package not installed: "--allow-dirty". Skipping.`

However, then after that I dared to try `ionic build` and it failed with this error, which got me stuck for another 15 minutes:

`zone-flags.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation.`

It seems that the `polyfills.ts` uses the `.ts` extension in the include which is breaking the compilation.

I changed this line in `polyfills.ts`:

`import './zone-flags.ts';`

To this:

`import './zone-flags';`

AND IT COMPILED.

But did it `ionic serve`?

No. No it did not.

The browser showed this in the console:

`Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!`

So after [some more searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60183056/ionic-5-with-angular-9-angular-jit-compilation-failed-angular-compiler-not), I found that if you open `main.ts` and then add

`import '@angular/compiler';`

Near the top then all will be right and good with the world once more...

...unless your project then needs the markup breaking changes resolving, but [you're on your own for that](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).