# Importing angular2-calendar-heatmap causes JIT compilation error

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, heatmap

I'm working on an Angular application (version 9.0.3) and I recently wanted to implement a calendar module, so I browsed the web and stumbled across [angular2-calendar-heatmap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-calendar-heatmap). I decided this was fit for my project, so I decided to add it and it gave the following error:

[image]

**What I did:**

- I installed this dependency through `npm install angular2-calendar-heatmap` as stated in [the installation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-calendar-heatmap#installation).
- I declared (and exported) this component in my shared (that's why I also exported, because other modules import the module that exports this) angular module, as stated in [the installation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-calendar-heatmap#installation).

**What I tried**

- I tried importing it, instead of declaring it in my module, but this did not change anything about the error.
- I checked if the dependy was correctly added in my `package.json`, which it is as `"angular2-calendar-heatmap": "^0.2.2"`

**What I already know**

- I'm 100% sure that this package is causing this error because without the error it functions normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a way to get rid of the error thanks to an answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60183056/ionic-5-with-angular-9-angular-jit-compilation-failed-angular-compiler-not). I simply quit the current server and restarted it with `ng serve`.

However, I still have other errors. I get `Cannot declare 'CalendarHeatmap' in a NgModule as it's not a part of the current compilation.`because CalendarHeatmap is added in declarations, so changed it to imports, but that also didn't solve the issue because this gave the following error: `Appears in the NgModule.imports of SharedModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class`

However, I found another package that also offers calendars and more detailed, it's called [angular calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar) and seems to offer more options. I also got the same error here. I just had to close the server and restart it with `ng serve`and then I got it to work.