# Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded

Tags: angular, angular-material, ionic5

Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!

- JIT compilation is discouraged for production use-cases! Consider AOT mode instead.
- Did you bootstrap using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server'?
- Alternatively provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.

Getting this error when build production build in dev mode not getting any error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic 5 with Angular 9 - Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60183056/ionic-5-with-angular-9-angular-jit-compilation-failed-angular-compiler-not)

Comment: That all solution not work for me

Comment: Re-creating android platform fixed the issue for me.
Check out: [blank-screen-angular-jit-compilation-failed-angular-compiler-not-loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70098226/blank-screen-angular-jit-compilation-failed-angular-compiler-not-loaded)

Comment: Re-creating android platform fixed the issue for me.
Check out: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70098226/blank-screen-angular-jit-compilation-failed-angular-compiler-not-loaded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late to answer this, but since this came up first on Google Search results, my fix could be helpful to someone else (might even help me in future ;) ).

If your app is using `HttpClient` for making any HTTP calls, probably you did similar mistake as me and imported `HttpClient` instead of `HttpClientModule` & ended up with the error message from question.

Simply replace the `HttpClient` with `HttpClientModule` in your `imports` array in `@NgModule` & add import the class.

```js
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, ProductListComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

Answer (score 8):

You could try any of the following solutions:

**Solution 1**

Run the following command to update all dependencies as their might have some incompatibilities:

```
npm update
```

**Solution 2**

Make sure you have already imported `'@angular/compiler'` at the very top of your `main.ts` file.

Now set the following line

```
aot=true
```

in `angular.json` file.

Also, set the following line

```
scripts{
  "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first- only --create-ivy-entry-points"
}
```

in `package.json` file and then delete `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and then run the following command:

```
npm install
```

**Solution 3**

Disable Ivy engine in `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": { "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true, "strictInjectionParameters": true, "enableIvy": false }
```