# The injectable 'PlatformLocation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

My Angular application is served via Node 16.13.0. After updating to Angular 13, I'm receiving the following error:

> JIT compilation failed for injectable [class PlatformLocation]
> file:///Users/btaylor/work/angular-apps/dz-outages-ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:4058
> throw new Error(message);
> ^

> Error: The injectable 'PlatformLocation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available.

> The injectable is part of a library that has been partially compiled.
> However, the Angular Linker has not processed the library such that JIT compilation is used as fallback.

> Ideally, the library is processed using the Angular Linker to become fully AOT compiled.
> Alternatively, the JIT compiler should be loaded by bootstrapping using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server',
> or manually provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.
> at getCompilerFacade (file:///Users/btaylor/work/angular-apps/dz-outages-ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:4058:15)
> at Module.ɵɵngDeclareFactory (file:///Users/btaylor/work/angular-apps/dz-outages-ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:32999:22)
> at file:///Users/btaylor/work/angular-apps/dz-outages-ui/node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2015/common.mjs:90:28
> at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:185:25)
> at async Promise.all (index 0)
> at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:281:24)
> at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
> at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:65:12)

I have tried numerous solutions, such as: [Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69083475/angular-jit-compilation-failed-angular-compiler-not-loaded)

Currently, I have `"type": "module"` in my package.json

I have updated my postinstall command to: `ngcc --properties es2020 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points`

I also added `import '@angular/compiler';` to my `main.ts` file.

The project will compile, but won't run via Node.

Comment: @RushPL me too. I need to find some time to make a minimal reproduction to raise a bug with the Angular team. I have another app using Universal with Angular 13 that works just fine.

Comment: This problem must be due to a specific dependency, as I was able to convert another Angular 12 app with the same architecture to 13 without issue.

Comment: Angular CLI shouldn't have this problem as it configures webpack+babel by itself.

Comment: By chance did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @WBuck No, I haven't had a chance to get back to this. I work on a ton of different projects at work and this upgrade feature on this app has been sidelined for a while.

Answer (score 18):

I believe I have found the solution (presuming you are using jest as your test runner). In the `test-setup.ts` file my project still was using the outdated import for jest-preset-angular. Instead of `import 'jest-preset-angular';` try using `import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';`.

This addressed the issue for me.

Comment: My scenario doesn't involve testing. I get the runtime error when serving the compiled code via Node.

Comment: It works with jest. I was not using `test-setup.ts` initially.

Comment: Did someone found any solution? :/

Comment: The change I had to make for this was in my jest.config.js file. I had `require('jest-preset-angular/ngcc-jest-processor')` at the top, but switched it to a globalSetup property on the exports as such: 
```module.exports = {
...,
globalSetup: 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup'`,
...
};```

Comment: No dice for me. Seem to still get the same error. And a new one to go along with it when removing testbed and using jest standalone.

" The injectable 'ActionsSubject' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available."

Comment: this worked for me, changing `jest-setup.ts`. thank you

Answer (score 7):

It seems angular 13 made `babel-loader` a mandatory requirement to link Ivy-native packages. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44026#issuecomment-974137408 - and the issue is happening as core Angular libraries are already compiled with the Ivy package format.

I haven't yet made the change in my own projects, but processing `.mjs` files with babel and a special linker should be enough.

```
import { dynamicImport } from 'tsimportlib';

/**
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
export default async (options: IWebpackOptions) => {
    const linkerPlugin = await dynamicImport('@angular/compiler-cli/linker/babel', module);
    
    const config: any = {
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.mjs$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    compact: false,
                    plugins: [linkerPlugin.default],
                },
                resolve: {
                    fullySpecified: false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'll make more updated to this post once I am able to test it myself.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't used custom webpack plugins with any of my projects. Do you have a reference for how to use/configure this with an existing project?

Comment: why you use `dynamicImport`? I saw a similar snippet without it `import linkerPlugin from '@angular/compiler-cli/linker/babel'; ` then ` ... {options: {plugins: [linkerPlugin],}` @RushPL

Comment: this should guide you how to setup custom-webpack in your code base `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack`

Comment: having too many issues trying to use async/await. webpack is determined to not let me use iit. able to use `import linkerPlugin from '@angular/compiler-cli/linker/babel';`. but then unable to resolve following error from babel-loader: `Error: .plugins[0] must be a string, object, function.` this points specifically to the line `plugins: [linkerPlugin.default]` any help?

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand, you use Angular Universal also.

I want to share my experience with the same problem which came to my project after updating Angular from v8 to v13.

First of all, I want to say that the main problem was with the incorrect started file for SSR. In my project, it was `server.js` and now it's `main.js`.
So, maybe your project also tries to start from the incorrect file which doesn't have the necessary code to start it.

More details:

I updated the project step by step, increasing the version as recommended by the Angular team and according to https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=8.2-13.0

Unfortunately, at every step, I only checked the version of SPA without SSR and only compiled the project to check that all is OK, but didn't start it with SSR. Now I can't say when the problem with the JIT compiler started.

And when I finished updating and fixing bugs with SPA, compiled the project with SSR, and tried to start it I saw this problem:

> Error: The injectable 'PlatformLocation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available.

I tried different solutions like you, but nothing helped. After that, I created a new clean project with ng13 and added Angular Universal. And compare my project with new, generated by Angular-CLI.

What I changed in my project(sorry, I can't show the project - NDA):

1. `angular.json`

```js
"projects": {
  "projectName": {
    ...
    "architect": {
      ...
      "server": {
        ...
        "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            //"main": "src/main.server.ts", //removed
            "main": "server.ts", //added
            ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. package.json

```js
"scripts": {
  ...
  //"serve:production:ssr":   "node dist/server --production" // removed. It was incorrect file server.js which gave the error from this case
  "serve:production:ssr":   "node dist/server/main --production", // added
  ...
  "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es5 browser module main --first-only" // added. In my case, actual version is es5
}
```

3.server.ts

```js
import 'zone.js/node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
...
// after all imports I inserted previous code into function run()

...
export function run() {
  // previous code from project with some small changes
}

//and added next code from clean project:

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
    run();
}

export * from '../src/main.server';
```

4. src/main.server.ts

```js
// was only:
export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';

// replaced by code from clean project:

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Initialize the server environment - for example, adding DOM built-in types to the global scope.
 *
 * NOTE:
 * This import must come before any imports (direct or transitive) that rely on DOM built-ins being
 * available, such as `@angular/elements`.
 */
import '@angular/platform-server/init';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}

export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

5. src/main.ts

```js
...
//this part of code
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    platformBrowserDynamic()
        .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});

// replaced by

function bootstrap() {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
};


if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    bootstrap();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bootstrap);
}

//but I don't think it plays a role in solving the JIT problem. Wrote just in case
```

6. tsconfig.server.json

```js
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app-server",
    "module": "commonjs",// it's only in my case, I don't have time for rewrote server.ts now
    "types": ["node"],
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ],
  "include":["server/**/*.ts","node/*.ts"],
  
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "./src/app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

Ok, I think that's all. After all these edits I don't have file /dist/server.js  and start the project from /dist/server/main.js without error from this case.

N.B.: When I was updating the project step-by-step I noticed that the process of updating nguniversal by Angular-CLI didn't change anything in the project. Only the version of packages. That's why I recommend comparing your project with an actual clean project manually

Comment: Well, I get a different error now. When running `serve:ssr` I get: `SyntaxError: Strict mode code may not include a with statement`

Comment: I think it can be some bug in the project. Maybe this is a reason: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34970#issuecomment-581838896.

Comment: I saw that same link when investigating, but I've updated my code to no avail. I think I'll probably have to create a new project and start adding my code back piece by piece until it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem in my case was missing the following configuration in the jest.config.js file:

```
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts']
```

[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4hJ4.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was to add the following (which I guess forces the compiler to be present for angular):

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FormPreviewEventsService],
    }).compileComponents();
```

The code sits in the beforeEach() for Jest.

I still create my service like I did before:

`service = new FormPreviewEventsService();`