# Has anyone ever successfully bundled an Angular 13 application with Webpack 5?

Tags: angular, webpack

I am attempting to upgrade an old project from Angular v6 up to an Angular LTS version. I was moving up the versions and when I got to version 13, I had to upgrade Webpack from 4 to 5. I thought it would be easiest just to create a new basic Angular app and attempt to bundle it using Webpack before attempting my project. I am running into so many issues.

I think the main issue revolves around this: [The injectable 'PlatformLocation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70127946/the-injectable-platformlocation-needs-to-be-compiled-using-the-jit-compiler-b)

How do I asynchronously load this loader into my webpack.config?

I continue to get errors when I attempt to require the babel LinkerPlugin, I am using esModules not commonJS. I am also on nodejs 14.20.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-webpack-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "path": "webpack-dev-server --version",
    "path2": "webpack --version",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.config.js --progress --port 8080",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production --node-env=production",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "test": "ng test",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode=development",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode=production --node-env=production",
    "serve": "webpack serve"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.1302.1",
    "@angular/animations": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.4.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^13.3.11",
    "@types/ws": "8.5.4",
    "html-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tsimportlib": "^0.0.5",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.4.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@webpack-cli/generators": "^3.0.7",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.63.6",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
    "typescript": "4.4.4",
    "webpack": "5.76.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  },
  "description": "My webpack project"
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilationMode": "partial",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": false,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
// Generated using webpack-cli https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli

const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ngToolsWebpack = require('@ngtools/webpack');
const dynamicImport = require('tsimportlib');


  const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production';


  const config = {
    entry: {
      'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
      'app': './src/main.ts',
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: "[name].js"
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    devServer: {
      open: true,
      host: 'localhost',
      historyApiFallback: true
    },
    plugins: [
      new ngToolsWebpack.AngularWebpackPlugin({
        tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json'

        //  entryModule: helpers.root('src/app/app.module#AppModule'),
        //  sourceMap: false,
      }),

      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
        inject: 'body'
      }),

      // Add your plugins here
      // Learn more about plugins from https://webpack.js.org/configuration/plugins/
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: 'html-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
        {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/i,
          type: 'asset',
        },
        {
          // Regular rule for all non-library files
          test: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {loader: 'babel-loader'}, // Optional
            {
              loader: '@ngtools/webpack', // Required
              options: {
                directTemplateLoading: false, // See https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack
              }
            },
            {loader: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader'}, // Optional
          ]
        },

        // Add your rules for custom modules here
        // Learn more about loaders from https://webpack.js.org/loaders/
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js', '...'],
    },
  };

  module.exports = () => {

    if (isProduction) {
      config.mode = 'production';


    } else {
      config.mode = 'development';
    }
    return config;
};
```

Comment: Just curious: Why are you using webpack directly over using the build functionality of the angular cli?

Comment: This was a legacy app built by someone else using Webpack. I just assumed it would be easiest to continue doing so. I've never had to familiarize myself with the build aspect of things as I mostly just write code for apps that are already exist.

Comment: If there is no functional reason to use webpack directly I would look at porting the build over to using the cli / ng build instead as there is direct support for this from the angular team and it will likely be easier to support as well because the community of users using ng build is much greater than those using webpack directly on angular. Either way you go I wish you the best of luck.